# Creating Hotspot without proxy authentication from a ethernet internet with proxy

Tags: networking, android-wifi, internet-connection, proxy-server

I need to create a wifi hotspot in my laptop which does not require proxy to configured by wireless clients (Android phone). What i have is an ehternet connection, through which internet is accessible using http proxy with authentication. 
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming questions only, so unless you have one (which does not seem to be the case), your question is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for such a solution. So far the solution for me has been this:

> I have an authentication based proxy internet through ethernet. What I
>   want to do is to share this internet through an (non-authenticated)
>   open proxy. So, I install CCproxy software on laptop and create a wifi
>   Access Point (adhoc is not supported by android) sharing my ethernet
>   internet. Now, in CCproxy, I go to Options > Advanced > Cascading and
>   check enable cascading proxy. Now, here I set my authenticated proxy
>   internet details. So what CCproxy is essentially doing is taking my
>   proxy internet and create another proxy server to distribute that
>   internet. In Account setting, I did "permit all", so that this is an
>   open proxy and needs no authentication. CCproxy creates a proxy server
>   at some IP and some port that will handle all the requests. So, if you
>   now go in your browser and enter this ip and port, it will be
>   forwarded through ccproxy and you will need no authentication. So far
>   what I essentially did was convert an authentication based proxy into
>   an open proxy.

And why I did that? B'coz, there is an app in android market "HTTP Proxy Settings" which works absolutely well if it's non-authenticated (open) proxy. It provides this setting to all major services like Market, Browser, games, various apps etc. Note that in my android proxy settings app, I had to give the proxy server address and port numbers that was set in CCproxy.

Now, in case you absolutely want to create a non-proxy based internet sharing. That's also possible. It can be done by creating a **transparent proxy** server. The procedure should be same as setting up a proxy server. But CCproxy can't do that. So, you'll have to look for some other software for that (Squid can do that actually).